# Table not updated with new row

Tags: javafx, tableview, observablelist

I finally got the content into my table (because I've been mastering that mystery out for ages!). Now I'd like to add new Items to the list AND automatically update the table. I thought an ObservableList would do the trick but there seems to be more to it. Can you provide me with a solution?

**Controller class:**

```
package controller;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

import db.ItemLijst;
import db.Klant;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import model.Item;
import model.ItemTypes;

public class SchermController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Item> tblItems;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Klant> tblKlanten;
//  @FXML
//  private TableView<Uitlening> tblUitleningen;
    @FXML
    private Button btnItemToevoegen;
    @FXML
    private Button btnKlantToevoegen;
    @FXML
    private Button btnRegistreer;
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<ItemTypes> cbTypes;
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Item> cbItems;
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Klant> cbKlanten;
    @FXML
    private TextField tfTitel;
    @FXML
    private TextField tfVoornaam;
    @FXML
    private TextField tfAchternaam;
    @FXML
    private TextField tfStraat;
    @FXML
    private TextField tfNummer;
    @FXML
    private TextField tfPostcode;
    @FXML
    private TextField tfGemeente;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Item, String> tcID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Item, ItemTypes> tcType;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Item, String> tcTitel;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Item, String> tcUitgeleend;
    private ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
            /*
             * ItemLijst is a static object (or object with all static 
methods). the CD, Film and Spel classes automatically add their record to 
this class. Literally translated it means ItemList. I thought by making this 
an ObservableList, the table would be automatically update its records 
depending on a change to this variable (ItemLijst.items<Item>)?
             */
        items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ItemLijst.getItems());

        tcID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("ID"));
        tcType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, ItemTypes>("Type"));
        tcTitel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("Titel"));
        tcUitgeleend.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("UitgeleendString"));
        tblItems.setItems(items);

        // Item types
        cbTypes.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(ItemTypes.values()));

        btnItemToevoegen.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                itemToevoegen();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println("Probleem: " + e1.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

/**
* This is the method which I use to add a new item to the CD, Film or Spel 
class (which inherits the Item class).

*/
    private void itemToevoegen() throws Exception
    {
        // Validatie
        if (cbTypes.getValue() == null ) {
            throw new Exception("Je moet een type kiezen");
        } else if (tfTitel.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("Je moet een titel ingeven");
        }

        Class<?> klasse = Class.forName("model." + cbTypes.getValue().toString());
        Constructor<?> cons = klasse.getConstructor(String.class);
        cons.newInstance(tfTitel.getText());
    }
}
```

**FXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="438.0" prefWidth="743.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.SchermController">
   <children>
      <TabPane layoutX="-1.0" prefHeight="438.0" prefWidth="744.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab closable="false" text="Items">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="367.0" prefWidth="766.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="tblItems" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="343.0" prefWidth="714.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="tcID" prefWidth="303.0" text="Item ID" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="tcType" prefWidth="76.0" text="Type" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="tcTitel" prefWidth="236.0" text="Titel" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="tcUitgeleend" prefWidth="98.0" text="Uitgeleend" />
                          </columns>
                        </TableView>
                        <ChoiceBox fx:id="cbTypes" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="365.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfTitel" layoutX="201.0" layoutY="365.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="352.0" promptText="Titel van item" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnItemToevoegen" layoutX="592.0" layoutY="365.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Toevoegen" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab closable="false" text="Klanten">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="tblKlanten" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="343.0" prefWidth="714.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="89.0" text="Klant ID" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="87.0" text="Voornaam" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="105.0" text="Achternaam" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="154.0" text="Straat" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="54.0" text="Nr" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="96.0" text="Postcode" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="128.0" text="Gemeente" />
                           </columns>
                        </TableView>
                        <TextField fx:id="tfVoornaam" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="365.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="105.0" promptText="Voornaam" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfAchternaam" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="365.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="94.0" promptText="Achternaam" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfStraat" layoutX="243.0" layoutY="365.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Straat" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfNummer" layoutX="396.0" layoutY="365.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="32.0" promptText="Nr" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfPostcode" layoutX="431.0" layoutY="365.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="Postcode" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfGemeente" layoutX="494.0" layoutY="365.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="130.0" promptText="Gemeente" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnKlantToevoegen" layoutX="635.0" layoutY="365.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="93.0" text="Toevoegen" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
            <Tab closable="false" text="Uitleningen">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="tblUitleningen" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="343.0" prefWidth="714.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="92.0" text="Klant ID" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="324.0" text="Item ID" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="155.0" text="Start Uitleen" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="142.0" text="Eind Uitleen" />
                           </columns>
                        </TableView>
                        <ChoiceBox fx:id="cbItems" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="364.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="185.0" />
                        <ChoiceBox fx:id="cbKlanten" layoutX="244.0" layoutY="364.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="203.0" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnRegistreer" layoutX="497.0" layoutY="364.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="229.0" text="Registreer Uitlening" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You are initializing `items` twice to different values - this is unnecessary. It is also not necessary to wrap an `ObservableList` with a new `ObservableList`. But this is all beside the point - I don't see anywhere in your code where you add items either to `items` or to `tblItems`'s `items` property. Where is the data supposed to come from?

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I understand now! Keep in mind that when creating `items` in the first line of `initialize` you are creating a new `OnservableList`, with the initial items from `ItemLijst`. Any subsequent changes to `items` will be reflected by this observable list, but *not* changes to `ItemLijst` - as it is not observable itself (if I understand correctly)

Comment: I tried before to change the List<Item> variable that is located in the ItemLijst class to ObservableList, but that didn't solve it before (when I had two different windows for the table and item adding section, but I combined those into the same window to stay with one controller in order to make the OBL work, but it didn't). I'll try it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-) you will find:

> `public static <E> ObservableList<E> observableArrayList(Collection<? extends E> col)`
>
> Creates a new observable array list and adds a content of collection col to it.

So in fact, you are creating a new `ObservableList` and adding the initial items to it. The simplest solution would be to have `ItemsLijst` have an `ObservableList`, and return it in `getItems`. Then you should only have to do

```
tblItems.setItems(ItemsLijst.getItems()); // I corrected the class name
```

Comment: It did the trick this time. Thanks for the help. Love you brother/sister!